# Rotating images on websites by using chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, css, dom, google-chrome-extension, rotation

I am trying to make a chrome extension that when clicked rotates the images on the page. (Purpose : many times images are sent on whatsapp are 90 degrees rotated and when viewing them on whatsapp web (laptop screen) is very annoying. I don't know if there is any way to rotate it directly without downloading so I thought it would be useful to make chrome extnesion which on clicking rotates images by 90 degrees.)
I am sending a signal from background.js  to content.js whenver the extension icon is clicked.

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMsg);
let count = 0 ;
function gotMsg(request, sender, sendResponce) {
    console.log(request.txt);
    if (request.txt == "rotate") {
        count+=1;
        let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        for (img of images) {
            rot=String(90*count);
            img.style.transform = "rotate("+rot+"deg)";
        }
    }
}
```

But issue here is this can only rotate the image but the img tag may be contained in some divs and as those divs are not being touched the image is getting rotated but some part of it gets cut and is not visible when image is rotated by 90 deg or 270 deg.

[image without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itNvB.png)
[image with rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Yi7.png)

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(btnClicked);
function btnClicked(tab){
    console.log("btn clicked");
    console.log(tab);
    let msg = {
        txt:"rotate"
    }
    // sending message
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,msg);
}
```

using manifest version-2

I have tried to swap image's length and width but that doesnt work as div that contains it is not affected by that.
Help me in finding out how to get all the parent tags inside which there lies an img tag. (as i think that would help in solving the issue.)

I am Beginner in javascript and chrome extension making so please elaborate on the possible ways to solve the problem.

Comment: There's no universal method to update the outer layout because each site is unique.

Comment: So i should target particular websites where I want this chrome plugin to work and inspect their html code to see their heirarchy in html to find parent tags of the img tags.

Comment: You could think about adding a click event handler at body level in content script. When the target of the click is an IMG tag you open a big modal div above the main page, copy a clone of the target image into that modal div and rotate and zoom the image as you wish.

Comment: @Robbi thanks for the suggestion. I shall try that